# Redirecting specific logs from systemd service to a separate file doesnt work

Tags: ubuntu, logging, systemd, syslog, rsyslog

I have done below configuration to redirect the docker logs to `/var/log/docker.log`

In `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=docker-engine
```

In `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-docker.conf`

```
if $programname == 'docker-engine' then /var/log/docker.log
if $programname == 'docker-engine' then ~
```

Then , I did

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

But , when I do `cat /var/log/docker.log` , I cannot see such file.
I am using 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

1) just create log file

```
touch /var/log/docker.log
chown syslog:adm /var/log/docker.log
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

2) if previous variant don't work, try to change `/etc/rsyslog.d/20-docker.conf` like this

```
if $syslogtag contains 'docker-engine' then /var/log/docker.log
if $syslogtag contains 'docker-engine' then stop
```